# My website is not responsive in Bootstrap 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am making a portfolio website for my school. I have to finish it in a few weeks but I am totally not good at CSS and HTML. I learned how to set up a Bootstrap website, but when I open it on my phone it just puts every object underneath each other.

I have tried to ask my teacher but she doesn't know how to fix this. She isn't really experienced either.

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Stage | Luc Schaft</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
 


    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
    
</head>
    
    
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
    
    
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    

<!--Issue-->
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
<main>
<div id="section2" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-12"><br><br><br><br><br> </div>

 <div class="col-md-1 col-6"> </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
 
 <h3>
 PR<span style="color:#e52421;">O</span>JECTEN
   </h3> 
  
 <p>
 Voor school maak ik meerdere projecten om al mijn geleerde technieken toe te passen in 1 grote opdracht.
<br><br>
Hierdoor laat ik zien wat ik kan en hoe ik te werk ga. Ik leer hierdoor ook heel veel en ik vind het leuker dan losse kleine opdrachten
<br><br>
Bij elk project is er een fase voor onderzoek, een fase voor schetsen en een fase voor het uitwerken voor je schetsen. 
 </p>
 </div>
    
 <div class="col-md-1 col-6"> </div>
 
  <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
<div class="hover07 column">
  <div>
  <figure> <a href="projecten.html#section2" target="_blank"><img src="images/klantbanner.jpg" height="300px"/></a></figure>
<span>Ik en de klant</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <figure> <a href="projecten.html#section3" target="_blank"> <img src="images/kiekiebanner.jpg" height="300px" /></a></figure>
<span>Kiekie krant</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <figure><a href="projecten.html#section4" target="_blank"><img src="images/MHSbanner.jpg" height="300px"/></a></figure>
<span>Startup</span>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-2 col-6"> </div>
 
 </div>
    </div>
 <!--Issue-->
</main>    
</body>     
</html>
````

I expect it to be able to be seen on phone, but it's terrible as how it is now.

Edit:
Okay, so the images normally are in a row of 3 horizontally. When I open my website on phone, everything gets lined vertically underneath eachother.

Comment: _but it's terrible as how it is now._ We don't know how must be on iphone, so we can't help you.

Comment: Okay, so the images normally are in a row of 3 horizontally. When I open my website on phone, everything gets lined vertically underneath eachother.

Comment: You have to explain better. do you mean your carousel? doesn't work?

Comment: Don't see an element with the class "container" wrapping any of the rows or cols.

Comment: there are a lot of things that are not good in this code. There are some syntax error in your css, rules are not closed properly. In your html instead you put some stuff that is supposed to be inside the <head> tag, outside of it. Inside your <head> tag there are some duplicate <meta> tags, you're using 2 versions of jQuery which is not necessary, just use the latest. I saw you're using OwlCarousel... you put the base css and the owl base theme, but will never show up if you don't import the JS that makes it work. Anyway, i suggest you to read again the Bootstrap docs and how the grid works :)

Comment: i tried to run your code locally, and still after correcting some stuff and installing properly carousel and etc.., can't figure out how it is supposed to look both in desktop and mobile. I can't help you further if don't explain better what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

The Grid system is first thing one learns when they learning Bootstrap.  It is a mobile-first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns.  Your rows must be placed within a .container (for fixed-width) or .container-fluid (for full-width), this allows for proper alignment and padding.  There are four screen sizes: -xs- for extra small; -sm- for small; -md- for medium; and -lg- for large screen sizes.

Extra small devices are phones with screen width smaller than 768px; Small devices are tablets with a screen width of 768px and up; medium devices are desktops with a screen width of 992px and up; and large devices are large desktops with a screen width of 1200px and up.

```html
<div class="container-fluid marketing">
  <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/Harvard_healthy_eating_pyramid.jpg" alt="Healthy Eating" width="140" height="140" />
      <h2>Healthy Eating Plans</h2>
      <p>Ensuring that you eat correctly by following a proper diet is a responsible way of keeping your body healthy and fit.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details&raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/250px-Yang_cheng_fu_single_whip_application_2_75.jpg" alt="Spiritual Healing" width="140" height="140" />
      <h2>The Art of Spiritual Healing</h2>
      <p>With a variety of healing methods such as Tai Chi, Fen Shui and Taoism, you can choose any of these methods to improve your health of your body with slow-moving exercises and proper breathing.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details&raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img class="img=circle" src="images/220px-Taraxacum_plant.jpg" alt="Herbal Remedies" width="140" height="140" />
      <h2>Herbal Remedies</h2>
      <p>Remedies for symptoms of Stress, weak immune systems, certain illnesses can be found here.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details&raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->
  <hr class="featurette-divider" />
 
  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Choosing your <span class="text-muted"> Carrier Oil</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Grapeseed and sweet almond oil are the best general-purpose carrier oils, and to begin with you will only need one or the other.  In this oil-by-oil guide find our about the pros and cons of these and other carrier oils.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/145px-Olive_oil_from_Oneglia.jpg" alt="Carrier Oils" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="featurette-divider" />
 
  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Aromatherapy <span class="text-muted">and massage precautions</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">There are lots of advantages to using essential oils, especially for massage but there are conditions when home use of aromatherapy and meassage is best avoided.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/AromatherapyMassage2.jpg" alt="Aromatherapy precautions" />
  </div>
</div>
 
<hr class="featurette-divider" />
 
<div class="row featurette">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Wonders of the world<span class="text-muted"> Part 1</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">Secreted inside seeds, petals and even honeycombs, some of the ingredients used in aromatherapy come from far afield.  Here we tell you how you can use them to give yourself a healthier body.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/220px-Aloe_Vera.jpg" alt="Aloe vera" />
  </div>
</div>
 
<hr class="featurette-divider">
 
<div class="row featurette">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Wonders of the world <span class="text-muted">Part 2</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">Found inside eggs, fruit, clay and honey, many of the ingredients used in aromatherapy come from natural sources. Discover how to use them in health and beauty treatments.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/120px-Oenothera_macrocarpa_a1.JPG " alt="Evening Primose plant" />
  </div>
</div>
 
<hr class="featurette-divider" />
 
<div class="row featurette">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Wonders of the world <span class="text-muted">Part 3</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">From goat's milk to rice flour, many substances used in aromatherapy come from natural sources.  Discover how to use them here.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/200px-Jojoba.jpg" alt="Jojoba plant" />
  </div>
</div>
 
<hr class="featurette-divider" />
 
<div class="row featurette">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Tools of <span class="text-muted">the trade</span></h2>
    <p class="lead">Vaporizing essential oils in your immediate environment is a remarkably effective way to reap the benefits of aromatherapy.  But which method is best for you?</p>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/Collection_of_modern_synthetic_candles.JPG " alt="Aromatherapy candles" />
  </div>
</div>
 
<hr class="featurette-divider" />
```

Credits:[go through this, hope it helps](https://html5hive.org/create-a-fully-functional-mobile-website-with-bootstrap/)

Comment: Ive added <div class="container-fluid"> right on top  and </div> on the bottom of the div. It still aligns vertically instead of horizontally.